# Auth::check() is always false in middleware in Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have used middlewares for many Laravel applications, but this is a stupid situation never happened to me before. The middleware always returns false for `Auth::check()`

This is `routes` of `User` module

```
<?php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web', 'namespace' => 'Modules\User\Http\Controllers'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'UserController@index');
    Route::get('login', 'LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    Route::post('login', 'LoginController@login');
    Route::post('logout', 'LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
});
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin', 'prefix' => 'user', 'namespace' => 'Modules\User\Http\Controllers'], function () {
    Route::get('register', 'RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
    Route::post('register', 'RegisterController@register');
});
```

This is `AdminMiddleware` inside the `User` module

```
<?php

namespace Modules\User\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $log = Auth::check();
        dd($log);
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

and this is `kernel.php`

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    'admin' => \Modules\User\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class
];
```

But the result of `dd($log)` is always false. What is wrong here?!!!

Comment: My best guess would be that because you are not applying the `web` middleware additionally to the `admin` middleware, the `auth` middleware is not run and you are therefore not authenticated. But it's only a guess, so no answer.

Comment: What is your auth guard config? If it is session pls post your session driver and config. Basically need auth.php and session.php config files

Comment: @Namoshek I should write this? `Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin','web'], 'prefix' => 'user', `

Comment: @Namoshek the `web` middleware group is automatically applied to your default routes.php file by the `RouteServiceProvider`. So no need to add `web`

Comment: Then why did you add it to the other group of routes, which is in the same file according to your description? Are you sure it is added? If you add it manually, make sure to call `web` *before* `admin`, i.e. `Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'admin'], ...)`

Comment: I forgot to add that middleware in the route service provider of the`User` module. `Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'admin']` worked. thanks alot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need to add `web` middleware to User module routes group.
Because the session starts there.

Comment: Do you mean something like this `Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin','web'], 'prefix' => 'user', `?

Comment: the `web` middleware group is automatically applied to your default routes.php file by the `RouteServiceProvider`. So no need to add `web`

Answer (score 1):

Just saying, another solution is that you added it to the global middleware stack instead of the web middleware group! (Only add it to web, it can't be both)

Answer (score 0):

please append your middleware address:

```
\Modules\User\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class
```

to

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Modules\User\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class //this is your middleware.
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set your middleware's priority to be loaded after `StartSession`  to be sure it will be loaded after the session starts.

in `kernel.php`

```
protected $middlewarePriority = [
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,

     \Modules\User\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class

    \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckProfileRequiredData::class, // putting CheckProfileRequiredData after Auth priority is required! to perform it's check after auth middleware
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckUserMustPayWithoutAnsweringDietRequiredQuestions::class,
];
```